# How to pass parameter for backgroundColor?(flutter)

Tags: flutter, function, dart, dart-pub

```
Expanded myui() {
  return Expanded(
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        audio(1);
      },
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      child: const Text(
        "",
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

how pass parameters for this " TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red) "  with myui function?

Comment: Hello! I appreciate you reaching out with your question. If you're new to Flutter and have basic questions, it's always helpful to try searching for similar queries on resources like Google or the official Flutter documentation to strengthen your understanding. Nonetheless, welcome to StackOverflow. Happy learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update it as:

```
 Expanded myui(Color bgColor) {
  return Expanded(
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        audio(1);
      },
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: bgColor),
      child: const Text(""),
    ),
  );
}
```

User as:

```
myui(Colors.green);
```